# How to use custom algorithms in Azure ML Studio and Service?

Tags: azure, machine-learning

We have developed some custom algorithms in Python and we want to use this in Azure ML Studio or Service. How do I export them? And also, does Azure ML support Time series analysis, PCA etc? Any answers would be appreciated.